Laravel Gmail SMTP Issues on cPanel: Timeout & SSL Errors (Works Locally)
I'm trying to send emails using Laravel's Mail facade with Gmail SMTP on a cPanel server. While the configuration works perfectly on my local environment, on the server I'm encountering two different issues:

Timeout errors when trying to connect to Gmail's SMTP server
SSL certificate verification failures

These issues persist despite successful SSL and port tests. I've confirmed that basic connectivity works:

Port tests succeed (connection establishes in 71ms)
OpenSSL tests show successful TLS negotiation
Server can reach Gmail SMTP servers

I've tried multiple configuration approaches including:

Using both SSL (465) and TLS (587) ports
Different encryption methods (SSL/TLS)
Various SSL verification settings
Different SMTP hosts (smtp.gmail.com and smtp-relay.gmail.com)
Adjusting timeout values
Different authentication modes

Each attempt results in either a timeout or an SSL certificate verification error, even though the same configuration works flawlessly in the local environment.
Environment:

Laravel version 11.34.2
PHP 8.2.25
cPanel server
Gmail SMTP

Configuration Working on Local:
'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'url' => null,
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => 587,
            'encryption' => 'tsl',
            'username' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
            'password' => "app-password",
            'timeout' => null,
        ],


Error #1 - Timeout:
Error sending: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.


Configuration USED:
'smtp' => [
    'transport' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'encryption' => 'ssl',
    'username' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
    'password' => 'app-password',
    'timeout' => 5,
    'stream_options' => [
        'ssl' => [
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
        ]
    ]
],


Error #2 - SSL Certificate:
Error sending: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. 
Connection failed. stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. 
OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed


Configuration USED:
'smtp' => [
    'transport' => 'smtp',
    'host' => 'smtp-relay.gmail.com',
    'port' => 587,              
    'encryption' => 'tls',          
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'timeout' => 5,
    'auth_mode' => 'PLAIN',
    'stream_options' => [
        'tcp' => [
            'tcp_nodelay' => true,
        ],
        'ssl' => [
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true,
            'SNI_enabled' => true,
        ]
    ]
],



Port tests show successful connections:

$ time nc -zv -w 5 smtp.gmail.com 465
Connection to smtp.gmail.com 465 port [tcp/submissions] succeeded!
real    0m0.071s


OpenSSL test shows successful TLS negotiation:

$ openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465
...
New, TLSv1.3, Cipher is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
...
220-smtp.gmail.com ESMTP ready



Verified Exim settings:

$ sudo exim -bP accept_8bitmime
accept_8bitmime
$ sudo exim -bP smtp_accept_max_nonmail
smtp_accept_max_nonmail = 10


Tried both SSL (465) and TLS (587) ports
Tried different timeout values
Verified Gmail app password and 2FA settings
Added various SSL/TLS configurations and certificate verifications
Tried using smtp-relay.gmail.com

The connection tests succeed but Laravel's mailer consistently times out. The quick netcat connection (71ms) suggests the issue might be during SSL handshake or SMTP authentication, but I haven't been able to resolve it.
Any help would be appreciated.

Who is hosting your CPanel server?

@KIKOSoftware Azure

It could be that GMail is rejecting the actual login from Azure, but that doesn't really explain the errors you get. You could try this option  just to see if something like that helps. Security is often an obstacle. Also, both Microsoft and Google are companies that have their own way of doing things, trying to get the two to talk to each other can be difficult.
